# Running all vs single test

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, testing

I have a test extracting data from oracle via forking. What we doing is comparing the price of the eth. When I run the cmd by `npx hardhat test test/test.ts` test is working fine. However when running `npx hardhat test` all the other test passes but not the oracle one. I have also run `npx hardhat test --network localhost`. It fails on both cases regardless.

Please provide a detailed answer if possible. Thanks

Comment: it seems your tests are not idempotent, so their ordering matters. Impossible to provide a more detailed answer, since this depends a lot on your code. So just make sure your tests have no indirect dependencies to each other.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen, I see your point. However, the test I'm running is recently developed by me. The rest of the tests were done by another developer. They are not interdependent on each other.  It's a little strange but I believe there is an explanation behind it.